# Make celery wait for task to finish

Tags: django, task, celery

I want celery to wait for a specific task to finish, therefore I installed the celery-results-backend beside celery itself. But I don't understand how I have to write my task call in order to wait as I currently get the following error:

```
example_task() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_pk'
```

views.py:

```
def example(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'GET':
        result = example_taks.apply_async(user_pk=user.pk)
        result_output = result.wait(timeout=None, interval=0.5)
        return redirect('something')
    else:
        args = {'user': user}
        return redirect(reverse('something'), args)
```

tasks.py:

```
def example_task(user_pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)
    try:
       ...
```

previously I called the talks like that:

```
def example(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'GET':
    example_task.delay(request.user.pk)
    ...
```

This was working fine but did not wait for task to finish.

If I Just do:

```
result = allocate_new_bch_address.apply_async(request.user.pk)
```

I also get a error:

```
example_task() argument after * must be an iterable, not UUID
```

Comment: If you are waiting for the task to finish why use celery at all? It would be better just to run the method directly in the view

Comment: This could totally kill my idea of application scaling with k8s

Comment: Just scale up the number of django workers rather than the number of celery workers?

Comment: Well that might not be a good Idea. If you have a large scale application you maybe dont want the same containers handling your tasks as they already handling user requests, beside there would be no option to set the number of web instances or the number of celery worker instances. Don't like the idea, sry. Can we maybe focus on the problem?

Comment: Waiting for a task to complete would be taking up one of your django workers as it would be blocked until the task completes...

Comment: even with apply_async? Isn't the idea of that to exactly not having this issue?

Comment: I'm asking because currently I have the problem with the delay function like shown above. If one task is triggert from user 1 anmd a second from user 2 at the same the one of my results gets lost in the wild.

Comment: With apply_async you should not wait for the result. It's for offloading work that can be done asynchronously to the request/response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210520/discussion-between-markus-brede-and-iain-shelvington).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you're using `apply_async()` wrong. The function accepts your task's arguments packed as a tuple (args) and dictionary (kwargs) as seen [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async). This is because you can specify additional parameters that define how the task should run.  On the other hand, `delay()` [only accepts your task's args and kwargs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.delay). `delay()` is sufficient in most cases.

You can either do this:

```
 example_taks.apply_async(kwargs={"user_pk":user.pk})
```

Or this:

```
example_tasks.delay(user_pk=user.pk)
```

You can also use positional arguments but I would  recommend using kwargs when possible.

Second, waiting for an async task as soon as submitting it defeats the purpose of Celery. To wait for a task to finish you need to call [get()](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.get) on the result:

```
result = example_tasks.apply_async(kwargs={"user_pk":user.pk})
result_output = result.get()
```

Comment: After switching to gunicorn production server your sugestion semms to result into the following error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61155267/celery-no-result-backend-is-configured-while-using-gunicorn

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you wait for the result.

```
result = example_tasks.apply_async(kwargs={"user_pk": user.pk})
# Do some other things while celery is running with the task

# Sync up with the task
result.wait(timeout=10) # seconds
if result.result == 1:
    print("Do something")
```